# What does $\partial B_r(0) $ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

What does $\partial B_r(0) $ mean?

I don't understand because $\partial$ is the symbol of partial derivative, meanwhile $B_r(0)$ is a ball.

Comment: It's a typical notation for the *boundary* of a set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the [boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) of the ball.